# how to convert decimal 49.25 to hexadecimal?

Tags: binary

please explain step by step procedure on how to convert 49.25 to hexadecimal.
I don't understand how to convert the decimal part.

Comment: **Hint:** $.25_{10} = \frac{1}{4}$.  What is a quarter of $16$?

Comment: How about you multiply by $16$, convert to hexadecimal then shift the digits to the right once to get the original number

Comment: To right number $N$ in hexidecimal you solve $N = a*256 + b*16 + c*1 + d*\frac 1{16} + e*\frac 1{256} + .....$.  It's easy to see that $49 = 3*16+1$ so $49_{10}=31_{16}$.  But now you need to figure out what $0.25_{10} = d*\frac 1{16} + e*\frac 1{256} + ....$.  And we now $0.25 = \frac 14$ and so $\frac 14 = \frac ?{16}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz don't  you mean: How many $16$ths are one quarter?.... oh wait.  I guess I see what you meant.

Comment: Oh, wait... I guess I see what you meant.

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}=\frac{x}{16}\iff \frac{16}{4}=x$.  It is just another way of saying the same thing

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself $16^k \le 49.25 < 16^{k+1}$ for what power of $k$.

The answer is $16^1 \le 49.25 < 16^2$.

Then ask yourself $49.25 = n*16^1 + r$ for what integer $n; 0\le n < 16$ and for what value of $r; 0\le r < 16$.

The answer is $49.25 = 3*16^1 + 1.25$.

That was to get the digit for the $16^1$ place.  Now we need to get the digit for the $16^0 = 1$ place.

So ask yourself $1.25 = n*1 + r$ for what integer $n; 0 \le n < 16$ and for what value of $r; 0\le r < 1$.

The answer is $1.25 = 1*1 + 0.25$.

Now we need to get the digit for the $16^{-1} = \frac 1{16}$ place.

So ask yourself $0.25 = n*\frac 1{16} + r$ for what integer $n; 0 \le n < 16$ and for what value of $r; 0 \le r < \frac 1{16}$.

The answer to that if $0.25 = \frac 14 = 4*\frac 1{16} + 0$.

We got to $0$ and now we stop.

Put it all together and you have found that:

$49.25 = 3*16^1 + 1*16^0 + 4*16^{-1}$.

The hexidecimal notation for this is $49.25 = 31.4_{16}$.

Note:  This is equivalent to noting that $49 \frac 14=  4*10^1 + 9*10^0 + 2*10^{-1} + 5*10^{-2}$ so we say $49\frac 14 = 49.25_{10}$.

the only differences are we did our calculations based on $10$ and not $16$, and that somebody told as that FORTY-NINE has a meaning and we should know what it means just be looking at it.